# Query populate string based on dictionary lookup

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So I have the following query

```
        IQueryable<Feedback> query = db.Feedbacks;
        var result = query
            .Select(s => new FeedbackViewModel
            {
                businessId = s.Account.Businesses.FirstOrDefault().businessId,
                hireSuccess = s.hireSuccess.Value,
                useAgain = s.useAgain.Value,
                suggestions = s.suggestions,
                employees = numberGroups[s.numEmployees.Value]
            });
        return result;
```

And im getting the error

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.String get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

due to attempting to set the employees string from a dictionary lookup, the dictionary looks like this.

```
    public static Dictionary<int, string> numberGroups = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        { 0, "None" },
        { 9, "1 to 9" },
        { 19, "10 to 19" },
        { 49, "20 to 49" },
        { 100, "50 to 100" }
    };
```

The FeedbackViewModel looks like this

```
public class FeedbackViewModel
{
    public int businessId { get; set; }
    public bool hireSuccess { get; set; }
    public bool useAgain { get; set; }
    public string suggestions { get; set; }
    public string employees { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try adding an AsEnumerable() before the Select, or populate an list of anonymous type like already explained in the answer of Kosala W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to query something from the database. Linq To SQL does not support methods like `numberGroups[s.numEmployees.Value]`.

You may consider doing something like this.

```
          var query = db.Feedbacks.Select(f = > new
                {
                    businessId = s.Account.Businesses.FirstOrDefault().businessId,
                    hireSuccess = s.hireSuccess.Value,
                    useAgain = s.useAgain.Value,
                    suggestions = s.suggestions.Value,
                    numEmployees = s.numEmployees.Value
                }).ToList();


          var result = query
              .Select(s => new FeedbackViewModel
                {
                    businessId = s.businessId,
                    hireSuccess = s.hireSuccess,
                    useAgain = s.useAgain,
                    suggestions = s.suggestions,
                    employees = numberGroups[s.numEmployees]
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Entities does not support Convert.ToInt32, which presumably what one of your *.Value calls are implicitly doing. You'll need to parse to int outside LINQ first. I might be able to give more specifics if I could see the FeedbackViewModel.

Comment: I edited the question to included the FeedbackViewModel